# SageMaker is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

I'm following the automate_model_retraining_workflow example from SageMaker examples, and I'm running that in AWS SageMaker Jupyter notebook. I followed all the steps given in the example for creating the roles and policies.

But when I try to run the following block of code to creat a Glue job, I ran into an error:

```
glue_script_location = S3Uploader.upload(
    local_path="./code/glue_etl.py",
    desired_s3_uri="s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, project_name),
    sagemaker_session=session,
)
glue_client = boto3.client("glue")

response = glue_client.create_job(
    Name=job_name,
    Description="PySpark job to extract the data and split in to training and validation data sets",
    Role=glue_role,  # you can pass your existing AWS Glue role here if you have used Glue before
    ExecutionProperty={"MaxConcurrentRuns": 2},
    Command={"Name": "glueetl", "ScriptLocation": glue_script_location, "PythonVersion": "3"},
    DefaultArguments={"--job-language": "python"},
    GlueVersion="1.0",
    WorkerType="Standard",
    NumberOfWorkers=2,
    Timeout=60,
)
```

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateJob
> operation: User:
> arn:aws:sts::############:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-############/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource:
> arn:aws:iam::############:role/AWS-Glue-S3-Bucket-Access

This is how AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-############ looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "############",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "glue:UpdateCrawler",
                "glue:UpdateTrigger",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "glue:DeleteCrawler",
                "glue:UpdateSchema",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "glue:DeleteConnection",
                "glue:UseMLTransforms",
                "glue:BatchDeleteConnection",
                "lambda:PutProvisionedConcurrencyConfig",
                "glue:StartCrawlerSchedule",
                "glue:UpdateMLTransform",
                "lambda:PublishVersion",
                "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping",
                "glue:CreateMLTransform",
                "glue:CreateRegistry",
                "glue:StartMLEvaluationTaskRun",
                "glue:DeleteTableVersion",
                "glue:CreateTrigger",
                "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
                "glue:StopTrigger",
                "glue:CreateUserDefinedFunction",
                "glue:StopCrawler",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "glue:DeleteJob",
                "glue:DeleteDevEndpoint",
                "glue:DeleteMLTransform",
                "glue:CreateJob",
                "glue:ResetJobBookmark",
                "glue:CreatePartition",
                "lambda:PutFunctionCodeSigningConfig",
                "glue:UpdatePartition",
                "glue:RegisterSchemaVersion",
                "glue:ResumeWorkflowRun",
                "lambda:UpdateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCodeSigningConfig",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "glue:StartMLLabelingSetGenerationTaskRun",
                "lambda:UpdateCodeSigningConfig",
                "glue:CreateDatabase",
                "glue:BatchDeleteTableVersion",
                "lambda:DeleteAlias",
                "glue:DeleteSchemaVersions",
                "glue:BatchCreatePartition",
                "glue:CreateClassifier",
                "glue:UpdateTable",
                "lambda:DeleteProvisionedConcurrencyConfig",
                "glue:DeleteTable",
                "glue:DeleteWorkflow",
                "glue:DeleteSchema",
                "glue:UpdateWorkflow",
                "glue:CreateScript",
                "glue:StartWorkflowRun",
                "glue:StopCrawlerSchedule",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionEventInvokeConfig",
                "lambda:DeleteFunctionCodeSigningConfig",
                "glue:UpdateDatabase",
                "glue:CreateTable",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "glue:BatchStopJobRun",
                "glue:DeleteUserDefinedFunction",
                "glue:CreateConnection",
                "glue:CreateCrawler",
                "lambda:UpdateAlias",
                "glue:DeleteSecurityConfiguration",
                "glue:CreateSchema",
                "glue:StartJobRun",
                "glue:BatchDeleteTable",
                "glue:UpdateClassifier",
                "glue:CreateWorkflow",
                "glue:DeletePartition",
                "lambda:CreateAlias",
                "glue:CreateSecurityConfiguration",
                "glue:PutWorkflowRunProperties",
                "glue:DeleteDatabase",
                "glue:RemoveSchemaVersionMetadata",
                "lambda:PublishLayerVersion",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
                "glue:StartTrigger",
                "glue:DeleteRegistry",
                "lambda:PutFunctionConcurrency",
                "lambda:DeleteCodeSigningConfig",
                "glue:ImportCatalogToGlue",
                "glue:PutDataCatalogEncryptionSettings",
                "glue:UpdateRegistry",
                "glue:StartCrawler",
                "lambda:DeleteLayerVersion",
                "lambda:PutFunctionEventInvokeConfig",
                "glue:UpdateJob",
                "lambda:DeleteFunctionEventInvokeConfig",
                "lambda:CreateCodeSigningConfig",
                "glue:StartImportLabelsTaskRun",
                "glue:DeleteClassifier",
                "glue:StartExportLabelsTaskRun",
                "glue:UpdateUserDefinedFunction",
                "glue:CancelMLTaskRun",
                "glue:StopWorkflowRun",
                "glue:PutSchemaVersionMetadata",
                "glue:UpdateCrawlerSchedule",
                "glue:UpdateConnection",
                "glue:CreateDevEndpoint",
                "glue:UpdateDevEndpoint",
                "lambda:DeleteFunctionConcurrency",
                "glue:DeleteTrigger"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*",
                "arn:aws:iam::############:role/query_training_status-role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear from the IAM policy that you've posted that you're only allowed to do an `iam:PassRole` on `arn:aws:iam::############:role/query_training_status-role` while Glue is trying to use the `arn:aws:iam::############:role/AWS-Glue-S3-Bucket-Access`. So you'll just need to update your IAM policy to allow `iam:PassRole` role as well for the other role.

Comment: Thanks it solved the error. I'm new to AWS. I'm wondering why it's not mentioned in the SageMaker example.